# Visual studio 2012 cannot find SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have installed SharePoint server 2013 on my dev machine and it is working fine when I login as an administrator. and after that I installed Visual studio 2012 professional on the same machine. But seems that Visual Studio did not find SharePoint automatically , as when I tried to create a new SharePoint project from Visual Studio, the following error was raised “**A SharePoint server is not installed in this computer** ”.

Can anyone advice?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Visual Studio 2012 was released before the updated version of SharePoint there (were) some post install updates that had to be run.  I believe at this point, everything is bundled into VS 2012 Update 2 which was released recently.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188

You may also need to install the Office Developer Tools for VS 2012:  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/office-dev-tools-for-visual-studio